# How can I get images to work in a jspdf autotable in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, html2canvas, jspdf-autotable

I have created an Angular project and I am exporting an HTML table using jsPDF autotable. The table exports fine, except that I am trying to get an image to be exported in the table as well.

I am using html2canvas to convert a div element to an image which is working great. The image appears in the HTML table when I run ng serve, but when I export to PDF the table cell where the image is supposed to be is empty.

I have followed this live example here to try and get the image to appear in the printed table: https://codepen.io/someatoms/pen/vLYXWB
But I'm getting a few errors that I can't figure out.

Here are the relevant parts of my code (with some names changed to generic things):

component.html

```
<button id="downloadButton" type="button" (click)="downloadPDF()">
    Download PDF
</button>
<table id="my-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="5">Title</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="5">Subtitle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5" id="my-image">
          <!-- This is where the image will be injected -->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
        <th>Heading 3</th>
        <th>Heading 4</th>
        <th>Heading 5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let thing of things">
      <td>{{ thing.one }}</td>
      <td>{{ thing.two }}</td>
      <td>{{ thing.three }}</td>
      <td>{{ thing.four }}°</td>
      <td>{{ thing.five }}m</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

component.ts

```
  downloadPDF(){
    this.convertImage();
    let date = new Date();
    date.getTime();
    let dateString = String(date + '.pdf')

    const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF()

    autoTable(doc, { html: '#my-table', bodyStyles: {minCellHeight: 15},
    didDrawCell: function(data) {
      if (data.row.index === 2 && data.cell.section === 'body') {
         var td = data.cell.raw;
         var img = td.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
         var dim = data.cell.height - data.cell.padding('vertical');
         var textPos = data.cell.textPos;
         doc.addImage(img.src, textPos.x,  textPos.y, dim, dim);
      }
    }}, )

    doc.save(dateString)
  };

  convertImage() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("my-div")).then(function (canvas) {
      const converted = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg", 0.9);
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = converted;
      document.getElementById('my-image').appendChild(img);
    });
  }
```

The 2 main problems I'm getting it at "**var img = td.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];**"

- Property 'getElementsByTagName' does not exist on type 'HTMLTableCellElement | CellInput'.
  Property 'getElementsByTagName' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

And the other one is 2 lines below it at "**var textPos = data.cell.textPos;**"

- Property 'textPos' does not exist on type 'Cell'.ts(2339)

What am I missing here that the live example from the link I've posted has that I don't?

Comment: Hi Asmo, did you get any solution for this?